# Master - Detail Char in Sencha ExtJS 4.0

Tags: extjs, charts, highcharts, master-detail, sencha-charts

It is possible to have Master-Detail chart in HighCharts:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail/dark-blue

And this is very cool. Has anyone ever seen the same in Sencha ExtJS 4.0 or has an example of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that difficult. Have a look at

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.chart.Mask

In the first code chunk it explains how to get zooming functionality. With a bit of workaround you can get it to reset itself into the newly select zoom level.

Comment: Thanks Grigore! :) I'll try that approach.